# Increasing Order Search Tree - Can't find the bug in my solution

Tags: c++, pointers, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

```
class Solution {
public:
   void search(TreeNode* root, TreeNode*& dummy){
       if(root == nullptr)
           return;
       
       search(root->left, dummy);
       dummy->right = root;
       dummy = dummy->right;
       search(root->right, dummy);
   }
   TreeNode* increasingBST(TreeNode* root) {
       TreeNode* dummy = new TreeNode();
       TreeNode* itr = dummy;
       search(root, dummy);
       return itr->right;
   }
};
```

Hey all,

While solving a problem(https://leetcode.com/problems/increasing-order-search-tree/) in leetcode, I am getting error Deadlysignal. But if I change **dummy->right = root;**  to **dummy->right = new TreeNode(root->val);** the code works.

I don't want to create new nodes but instead want to change the links. Can anyone help me understand why this solution isn't working?

Comment: *"I don't want to create new nodes"* - then `TreeNode* dummy = new TreeNode();` shouldn't be in this either. Consider an alternative algorithm that repeated performs a right-rotation on the  active node (which starts as root), until there is no left child left, then advances down the right side and repeats. When you arrive at a node with no left or right child, you're done and you've degenerated your tree to a linked list. Rotations are common operations when maintaining a balanced tree, and would be great googlefu if you don't know how to do it.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but by "I don't want to create new nodes", I meant not creating the nodes in the Search method. The dummy node which I am creating in the increasingBST method is just to help with the return of increasingBST method.  Also If I am not wrong, I am kinda doing the rotations like you mentioned. Not sure what's going wrong though.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you don't clear the `left` reference of the current `dummy` node. The result tree should not have left children, and by keeping those, you create cycles. So clear `left`:

```
   search(root->left, dummy);
   root->left = nullptr;  // <--
   dummy->right = root;
   dummy = root;
   search(root->right, dummy);
```

Note that `dummy = dummy->right` is equivalent to `dummy = root` (also changed).

Comment: Did this answer your question? Any feedback?